# dojo.connect event object undefined

Tags: javascript, events, dojo, undefined, dom-events

I connected a function via `dojo.connect` to a `dojox.layout.ContentPane` according to Dojo's documentation:

```
dojo.connect(cp, 'onHide', function(e) {
    alert('test');
    console.log(e);
});
```

I expect argument `e` to be the triggered event object, but console output is `undefined`.
What's the problem here?

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you are connecting to.

- If you are connecting to a dom event (which your example is not), then you will get the dom event object passed into your function.
- If you are connecting to a function in a javascript object (which is what your example is), then the arguments passed into the function that is connected to (onHide) will be passed into your function.  I am guessing that there are no arguments that get passed into the `onHide` function.

Note: `dojo.connect` has been replaced with `dojo/on`.